# Which song was dubbed into the most languages?

Tags: language

I have seen that [*Let It Go*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_It_Go_%28Disney_song%29) from [*Frozen*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OC83NA5tAGE) was dubbed into [42 different languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let_It_Go_%28Disney_song%29#Other_languages).

Is there any song that holds the record for being dubbed into the most number of languages?

<sup>Please only include answers which cite from reliable sources.</sup>

Comment: Except for songs sung publicly at christian congregations, I guess?

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that. Yeah I would not such prefer songs.

Comment: I guess "Happy birthday to you" might be the song that has actually made it into the most languages, and even into the most recordings, but I assume we're talking about commercially released tracks?

Comment: Jeff Wayne's War of the Worlds was dubbed into a lot other languages - twice for Spanish as they found out later it's a slightly different for Mexican speakers.

Answer (score 4):

The [Guinness World Records website reports](http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/song-sung-in-the-most-languages-by-one-artistgroup) that the song 'Golden Dreams of Gandhiji' by Dr. Kesiraju Srinivas was recorded in 125 different languages. It was released as a double album titled 'The Path of Mahatma Gandhi' on 2 December 2009.